# Add dynamically div over div using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt

I have created a form using jsni in  gwt . I have some textboxes and a button within a div. Now, I want to add a div on the form div with text"Loading" on button click to show the transferring of values from client side to server side.
till i now I tried like

```
             var x=$doc.createElement("div");//first div
             var y=$doc.createElement("div")//second div
             x.appendChild(y);//to add div
```

but its not working.

Help me using javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can try out this

```
$("#button").click({
    $("#formdiv").append("#message_div").html("Contents transferring message");


    var timeout= setTimeout(function() {
          $("#message_div").hide();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: i am new to jquery can you tell me to create the div in jquery or it will work with javascript method

Comment: I wud recommend you to visit this link http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Comment: help me with javascript

Comment: Did u try the jquery one?

Comment: its not useful for me as i am geting exceptions.

Comment: the script i added in html file of gwt project its using google api because of it its creating some trouble. I had to add the jquery in gwt jsni. I have worked on javascript to try on it will be better..

Comment: Ur javascript code is also right, what error are u recieving?

Comment: my problem is that i want to show a div over my form. when i tried to do so by writing "loading" on innerhtml of inner div its showing below the lower div. other than that when i increased the height and width of lower div than also its showing the text below the button but inside div. i want to show the text in center as it seen in websites during page load. stuck in messy situation. getting no solution... help me it will be very kind of u

Comment: so kind of u if u can give me ur email id i will mail u my whole code. may be then u will be able to help

Comment: yeah no prob abhi06991@gmail.com

Comment: I just created a jsfiddle..check and tell me if thts wht u needed http://jsfiddle.net/abhi47/GNmh9/

Comment: i want the text to be in center but the text should be on the other div.

Comment: It is another div. check the code i have appended a new div and then placed the contents inside it